# sed - find path in file and replace in place pattern for that line

Tags: regex, bash, file, sed, grep

I have to remove root permissions entries in 15 files (servers) with NFS shares provided in separate file and to control this process - I want to do it server by server with some additional checks. I have 2 files, first called nfspaths looks like this example:

```
cat ./nfspaths:
/mnt/vol/virtserver1/sharename
/mnt/vol/virtserver2/sharename
/mnt/vol/virtserver4/sharename
```

and exportfs which looks like this:

```
cat ./exportfs:
/mnt/vol/virtserver1/sharename rw=host1,host2,host3,root=host1,host2,host3,host4,host5
/mnt/vol/virtserver2/sharename rw=host1,host2,host3,root=host1,host2,host3,host4,host5
/mnt/vol/virtserver3/sharename rw=host1,host2,host3
/mnt/vol/virtserver4/sharename rw=host1,host2,host3,root=host1,host2,host3,host4,host5
/mnt/vol/virtserver5/sharename rw=host1,host2,host3
```

I want to make a script that will look for nfspath in nfspaths and for that line will remove root permissions. I'm trying to use sed for this job and I've wrote something like this:

```
for nfspath in `cat nfspaths.list`
do
   sed -i -n -e "\,$nfspath,p" -e 's/,root=.*$//g' exports
done
```

, but this is not working as I expected, those 2 sed cmds works separately ok, but I can't find solution to mege them in one command.

What they do ? In "for" loop I'm getting a path (with slashes) and for that path sed should grep exportfs file (first occurrence: `sed -i -n -e "\,$nfspath,p"`) and second should remove pattern ",root=" to the end of that line. In above command sed works independently and is removing everything from exportfs file. I know that I should something else instead of second "-e" for sed, but I can't find with google any good example to do that.

What is wrong in this oneliner and how to improve it ?

Answer (score 2):

Any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. Just use awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $1 in a{sub(/,root.*/,"")} 1' nfspaths exports
```

No explicit loop required, no worrying about delimiter chars, etc.

You can use `-i inplace` with GNU awk 4.* if you don't like manually specify the tmp file, or just add `> tmp && mv tmp exports` to the end of the line otherwise.

Comment: Sorry for my late response - today I've checked your solution and it works like a charm :-) Could you please explain how does it works and what it does exactly and - what is most important for me - why this way ? Any suggestion where to look for good AWK introduction or tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can provide an argument like this to the `s/` command:

```
while read nfspath 
do
   sed -i -e "\,$nfspath, s/,root=.*$//" exports
done <nfspaths.list
```

Personal preference on changing to the `while read` but I think it's clearer and more straightforward.

I also got rid of the `g` argument since your anchor (`$`) means that by definition it will happen one time.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work in fact - after execution exports seems to be empty and I don't have a time for debugging it now, but thx for your try.

Comment: I just copy/pasted your sed options - without the `-n` it should work.

Comment: Yep, it works and do the magic :-) Thx a lot for your effort.